# JS: Play clip on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to fire a clip on mouseover and it doesn't work. I can log to the console but it seems I am doing something wrong to play the clip … What is it?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var clip1 = document.getElementById("clip1");
    var projects = document.getElementById("projects");

    function playClip1() {
        clip1.play();
        console.log("I should play clip1 now");
    }

    projects.addEventListener("mouseover", playClip1);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <audio id="clip1" src="clip1.wav"></audio>
   <a id="projects" href="index.html"> projects </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the element with ID "projects"?

Comment: It's the ID of a link

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play play() returns a promise.  Check whether the call fails or succeeds

Comment: Your code should work, I tested it locally and the sound played. Check the paths, the audio format, etc.

Comment: Do note, not all browsers play all types of audio format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: @Sébastien yes it must be a weird error on my side. I'll figure it out. Thanks for you help and for developing the web since 1997! ;)

Comment: Ha Ha! Sure ;) I hope you figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, but you may have more information on what's going on by using a promise.

The following code will log a message in both cases: success or error. The error message may be useful to you.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var clip1 = document.getElementById("clip1");
  var projects = document.getElementById("projects");

  function playClip1() {
    clip1.play()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    });
    console.log("I should play clip1 now");
  }
  projects.addEventListener("mouseover", playClip1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <audio id="clip1" src="http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/voices/dinner-is-served.wav"></audio>
  <a id="projects" href="index.html"> projects </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Posting answers saying _"It works..."_ is not useful, as a comment it is.

Comment: You might have noticed the handling of the promise... But feel free to downvote or flag.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question, and if that goes, then half of all given script answers could be _"Check the console"_ ... and I generally don't downvote a technical correct answer, more useful with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

May be your `src` audio file is missing on the path or something is wrong with your audio file loading/playing while hovering. I've tried with another audio file from wikimedia and it is working fine. I've put an extra `console.log()` message to check whether it is showing msg at the time of hover or not.

```js
 window.onload = function(){

  var clip1 = document.getElementById("clip1");
  var projects = document.getElementById("projects");

  function playClip1() {
    console.log('project link hovered');
    clip1.play();
    console.log("I should play clip1 now");
  }

  projects.addEventListener("mouseover", playClip1);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<audio id="clip1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Cello_Live_Performance_John_Michel_Tchaikovsky_Violin_Concerto_3rd_MVT_applaused_cut.ogg"></audio>
<a id="projects" href="index.html"> projects </a>
</body>
   </html>
```

See demo : https://jsbin.com/dijediduzu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Posting answers saying _"It works..."_ is not useful, as a comment it is.